# How many cards do you trash when you play a Chapel after having bought a Sewers?

Tags: dominion, dominion-renaissance

Chapel reads

> Trash up to 4 cards from your hand.

Sewers reads

> When you trash a card other than from this, you may trash a card from your hand.

Because the cards Chapel trashes are all at once, do you get to trash up to 4 more cards, or 1?

Comment: Thanks, @Conman, I wanted to make a dominion-renaissance tag myself but I lacked the reputation for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Sewers) Dominion Wiki you may

> trash an additional card for each card trashed.

It specifically gives example with Chapel.